# How to access the Windows 8 recovery partition?

Tags: windows, windows-8, partitioning, system-recovery

I upgraded my Asus UX32VD to a new SSD. Now I want to install Windows 8 again, but that is only on a recovery partition on the old HDD and I cannot acess that. Besides that I am not sure if that is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I recommend that you find the original Windows 8 ISO somewhere and install Windows from it. That way you won’t get preloaded with crapware.

Answer (score 1):

Use some Tool like Acronis to clone all partitions from the old to the new SSD.

Comment: The old HDD is no SSD, is that still possible? Will th new SSD be bootable like that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the recovery kit maker from Asus called 'Backtracker'  Its obscure but here is a direct link to the website.

http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008641/

Be careful of course when using it and make sure you read the instructions